# Method added via a category isn't being recognized

Tags: ios

I've added a category to UIApplication  however I'm getting an unrecognized selector error at runtime.

Now the thing is this code has existed and been working for 10 months in another project, so I know there's nothing fundamentally wrong with it. 
I am in the process of creating a new project and am re-using the source files from the other project. I have added them *unaltered* to the new project, and they still continue to work in the old project. So I know this code should work in the new project.

I am at a loss as to why the exact same code is working in one project but not in another.

For reference the category is:

```
@interface UIApplication (NetworkActivity)
- (void)resetNetworkActivity;
@end


The call which fails:
[[UIApplication sharedApplication]  resetNetworkActivity];


2012-10-18 14:19:26.134 IMS-Reference[5946:907] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIApplication resetNetworkActivity]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1e58e240'
*** First throw call stack:
```

Any thoughts why its not working?

Comment: Do you get any compiler warnings? Is the .m file for the category in the compile sources build phase for your target?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically, this is because your `*.m` file is not in the target's compile phases. So... just triple-check that :)

Comment: Doh, it was missing. BUT, adding it and rebuilding didn't solve the issue.

Comment: @Piepants odd - have you tried a clean build, now that it added to the right target? (no, that should not be necessary but it's worth a sanity check)

Comment: Fixed it: I exited Xcode and re-launched it, and then it started working.

Comment: @Piepants ok. is compiled into a static library or app? if static library, you have extra linker flags to verify.

Comment: @Piepants "*I exited Xcode and re-launched it, and then it started working.*" -- love that :)

Answer (score 0):

First off check to make sure you have actually compiled the category, I have noticed in XCode when you drag files from one project to another they do not get added to the compile sources section of build phases.